# React Native Dimensions Inconsistent Units

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I have a view width that has been set to 80 (using Native Base):

```
      <Box
        maxW="80"
        w="80"
        rounded="lg"
        overflow="hidden"
        borderColor="coolGray.200"
        borderWidth="1"
      >
```

There should be enough for 3 of these components to fit across a screen. When I use `const { width } = useWindowDimensions()`, the value for my iPad mini comes back as `1133` for the width.

When I do an inspection of the component, it comes back as being `328` in width.

How would I go about determining how many items can fit in a row when the dimensions don't seem to line up? E.g, Converting 80 to 328, or reducing 1133 to be in the same units as the view?

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that NativeBase units are a value of 4 dp. So for `w="80"`, it's 320dp.

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/discussions/5690